# How to test the container or image after docker build?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have the following Dockerfile

```
############################################################
# Purpose   : Dockerize Django App to be used in AWS EC2
# Django    : 1.8.1
# OS        : Ubuntu 14.04
# WebServer : nginx
# Database  : Postgres inside RDS
# Python    : 2.7
# VERSION   : 0.1
############################################################

from ubuntu:14.04

maintainer Kim Stacks, kimcity@gmail.com

# make sure package repository is up to date
run echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main universe" > /etc/apt/sources.list

run apt-get update

# install python

# install nginx
```

Inside my VM, I did the following:

```
docker build -t ubuntu1404/djangoapp .
```

It is successful.

**What do I do to run the docker image?**
**Where is the image or container?**

I have already tried running

```
docker run ubuntu1404/djangoapp
```

Nothing happens.

What I see when I run `docker images`

```
root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/var/virtual/Apps/DockerFiles/Django27InUbuntu# docker images
REPOSITORY             TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
ubuntu1404/djangoapp   latest              cfb161605c8e        10 minutes ago      198.3 MB
ubuntu                 14.04               07f8e8c5e660        10 days ago         188.3 MB
hello-world            latest              91c95931e552        3 weeks ago         910 B
```

When I run `docker ps`, nothing shows up

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have to give a command your container will have to process.

Example : **sh**

you could try :

```
docker run -ti yourimage sh
```

(-ti is used to keep a terminal open)

If you want to launch a daemon (like a server), you will have to enter something like :

```
docker run -d yourimage daemontolaunch
```

Use `docker help run` for more options.

You also can set a default behaviour with [CMD instruction](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#cmd) in your Dockerfile so you won't have to give this command to your container each time you want to run it.

**EDIT - about container removing :**

Containers and images are different.
A container is an instance of an image.
You can run several containers from the same image.

The container automatically stops when the process it runs terminates.
But the container isn't deleted (just stopped, so you can restart it).
But if you want to remove it (removing a container doesn't remove the image) you have two ways to do :

- automatically removing it at the end of the process by adding `--rm` option to `docker run`.
- Manually removing it by using the `docker rm` command and giving it the container ID or its name (a container has to be stopped before being removed, use `docker stop` for this).

A usefull command :

Use `docker ps` to list containers. -q to display only the container IDs, -a to display even stopped containers.

More [here](https://docs.docker.com/).

**EDIT 2:**

[This](https://www.docker.com/tryit/) could also help you to discover docker if you didn't try it.

Comment: thank you. Do I ever need to shutdown the container? if so, how?

Comment: I am confused. What's the purpose of the daemon?

Comment: You may have to run your docker container in the background, for example to run a web server. You can also do it without daemonize your container, but you have to let the container run in your terminal, that could be not practical.
Don't hesitate to read the official documentation and use the tutorial : It's really well done.

Comment: I also added some explanations about container removing. I hope it will help you. :)

Comment: Let's slow down a tad for me. 

Just because I have built an image, doesn't mean I have a container that is running. Yes?

https://docs.docker.com/articles/basics/ talks about Run Docker in daemon mode. Does the mean the same thing as 

`docker run -d yourimage daemontolaunch`?

Comment: If you build an image, you have a new "mould" you can use to make a container by running it. Building an image and running a container are two different things.

Comment: No, the docker daemon (mentioned in the link you gave) and a "daemonized" container  (the command you quoted) are also two different things. The docker daemon is the process that will run containers. The "daemonized" container is just a container that runs in the background.

Comment: Can give a better example on how to create a daemonized container? My image is ubuntu1404/djangoapp.

Comment: If you want to run an apache webserver (with a django app on it for example) you could run **docker run -d ubuntu1404/djangoapp /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND** for example. (This one is from one of my Dockerfiles, I can't give a more actual instance).

Answer (score 7):

> How to test the container or image after docker build?

In order to test you can add write a bash script which will do the job  https://blog.brazdeikis.io/posts/docker-image-tests

Btw, from the post, I see that it does not match the question from the title.

So, Added a link for the souls who arrived here based on the title...

Comment: It looks like the blog link needs to be updated to https://blog.brazdeikis.io/posts/docker-image-tests.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the latest shaded dist from https://github.com/dgroup/docker-unittests/releases:

   ```
   wget https://github.com/dgroup/docker-unittests/releases/download/s1.1.1/docker-unittests-app-1.1.1.jar
   ```
2. De fine an *.yml file with tests.

   ```
   version: 1.1

   setup:
   - apt-get update
   - apt-get install -y tree

   tests:

   - assume: java version is 1.9, Debian build
    cmd:    java -version
    output:
      contains:
       - openjdk version "9.0.1"
       - build 9.0.1+11-Debian

   - assume: curl version is 7.xxx
    cmd:    curl --version
    output:
      startsWith: curl 7.
      matches:
       - "^curl\\s7.*\\n.*\\nProtocols.+ftps.+https.+telnet.*\\n.*\\n$"
      contains:
       - AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API

   - assume:  Setup section installed `tree`
    cmd:     tree --version
    output:
      contains: ["Steve Baker", "Florian Sesser"]
   ```
3. Run tests for image

   ```
   java -jar docker-unittests.jar -f image-tests.yml -i openjdk:9.0.1-11
   ```

   https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSv72.png

Comment: Another tool to test containers (which was the original question) is [dgoss](https://github.com/aelsabbahy/goss/tree/master/extras/dgoss).